# saving meta/custom field to tag

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, tags

In my custom post type what I am trying to do is say I have select drop down option called party_ad. The value of the options are obtained via an RSS feed.

```
echo '<select name="ad_Tags" id="ad_Tags">';
  foreach ($rs['items'] as $item)
  {
   echo '<option value="'.$item[title].'" '. selected( $adTags, $item[title]).'>'.$item[title].'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';
```

I can save these data with no problems - however, what I want to be able to save the selected option as a tag to the custom post. I thought about doing it front end, ie if an option is selected then it adds the value to the post tag box, ideally though, I'd like to really do this server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [wp_insert_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) to create the tag and then [wp_set_object_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) to set it as the custom post tag:

```
//get the tag
$tag = $_POST['ad_Tags'];
//create the tag
$term_id= wp_insert_term(
    $tag, // the term 
    'post_tag', // the taxonomy
    array('description'=> 'term description','slug' => 'term-slug')
);
//set the tag
wp_set_object_terms(  $post_id, $term_id, 'post_tag' );
```

Comment: Thanks for this - got it working, and just to clarify - if I wanted to say this with the post...ie the post is tagged as xyz. Could you not just use wp_set_post_terms instead?

Comment: `wp_set_post_terms` is a wrapper for `wp_set_object_terms` so they both basically do the same.

Comment: Glad i could help.